# Print average of integers in decimal form

Tags: c, integer, double

I have written a program where user can enter integers and in the ''menu'' choose option 'c' to calculate the average of all integers entered. My problem is that the program displays numbers as a whole instead of deciaml, like 3 instead of 3.7.

I have tried changing variables to double, float but it does not work. I'm gonna post my main and my avg function. In the main I cannot change variable types since other functions that use this variables will be affected. (Please ignore the placing of curly brackets.)

```
int main (){

    int measurements[10];
    int nrOfMeasurements = 0;
    char ch;

    while(1){
        printf("\nView(v)Enter(e)Compute(c):");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        switch(ch){
              case 'c':printf("Avg:%d\n", avg(measurements,nrOfMeasurements));
                       break; 
              }
      }
}

int avg(int a[], int n){

    int i;
    double sum=0,avg;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum += a[i];
    }
    avg=sum/n;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the %d format ?

Comment: I tried %.2f but i just get 0.00 as answer.

Comment: Don't try formats randomly. Figure out which you need.

Comment: nrOfMeasurements = 0; Your program should signal a division by zero.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's because this is not a [mcve].

Comment: @YvesDaoust What I meant is that, this is not the _exact_ code OP is running. They tried to skim the code (rather unsuccessfully, I say), but there are other significant parts which are also missing. This code, as-is , will have the problem you mentioned, but I suspect this is not the actual/complete code.

Comment: @lata27 "I need %.2f but it only gives me 0.00." --> Save time.  Enable all warnings.  With a good compiler, it will warn about `"%f"` with an `int` and conversion in `return avg;`  Faster than posting on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 int avg(int a[], int n){
```

to

```
 double avg(int a[], int n){
```

and use it like

```
printf("Avg:%f\n", avg(measurements,nrOfMeasurements));
```

If you need floating point output, you need to use the proper type and conversion specifiers.